# read perl stout from php

Tags: php, json, perl

I have a perl script that returns json string.

```
$json = `/usr/bin/perl /var/www/private/data.pl`;
```

data.pl returns `{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}`

**What is the best way to access json string in $json variable ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is

```
exec('/usr/bin/perl /var/www/private/data.pl',$jsonArray);
$json = reset($jsonArray);
```